# How to represent the URL as it is in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url, exception

I want to pass the exception Url as a string to a method that I have created , so that it shows the exception Url in the mail (that is sent).

I have  done the following in my `ApplicationError()` event in my `Global.asax`

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    Dim lastException As Exception = Server.GetLastError()

    If (lastException Is Nothing) Then
        Return
    End If

    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    Dim myMethodforMail As New myMethodforMail()
    Dim exUrl As String = context.Request.Url.ToString()
    Dim webServerName As String = Server.MachineName
    myMethodforMail.HandleApplicationError(exUrl, webServerName)
    Server.ClearError()
End Sub
```

But the url is printed as      http://localhost:22035/examplepage.aspx?PageNumber!0331

instead of  http://localhost:22035/examplepage.aspx?PageNumber=650331

could anyone kindly help me how to decode the `!` in the Url and represent the Url as it is,  please . ThankYou.

Comment: 1) Could it be that the error *is* that there is a "!" in the URL instead of "=65"? 2) Have you checked the value of `exURL` before passing it to `myMethodforMail.HandleApplicationError`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton , I have checked everything and it is fine, only the system is encoding the =65 as '!'

Comment: @AndrewMorton , To make it more clear, the `context.Request.Url.ToString()` is giving the string as http://localhost:22035/examplepage.aspx?PageNumber!0331 instead of    http://localhost:22035/examplepage.aspx?PageNumber=650331